# Why is object appearing as not defined, when console shows object contents?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What I was trying to accomplish, I thought, was simple. I want to be able to type my name into the text boxes, hit submit, and have the info print to the console inside an object. When I bring up the console, it appears to work. I can type different names, and it's printed into the console. However, if I try to then look up the Person object, I get an error that says it's undefined. What's happening?

https://jsfiddle.net/w0zwrqoa/

HTML

```
  <p>First Name</p>
  <input type="text" id="fname">
  <p>Last Name</p>
  <input type="text" id="lname">
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
```

JS

```
var Person = function (firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname; 
    this.lastname = lastname; 
}; 

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function() {

var fn = document.getElementById('fname').value; 
var ln = document.getElementById('lname').value;

function addPerson (person){
    console.log(person); 
}; 

var user = new Person (fn, ln); 

addPerson(user); 

};
```

Comment: What do you mean, "look up the person"?

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle?

Comment: and that too with capital P lookup Person

Comment: `user` is private, so you can't type it into the console...

Comment: I mean, if I go to the console and type "Person" it says "Person is not defined." If I type in Person, shouldn't I expect to see, "Person {firstname: "x", lastname: "x"}"

Comment: `Person` is a function, not an object. now, why you can't see it we can't tell...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w0zwrqoa/

Comment: ahh, that's a fiddle artifact, try https://jsfiddle.net/w0zwrqoa/1/, in which i can see `Person` just fine..

Comment: The console is separate from the code, and in it's scope there was never a defined `Person`. If you define person first in the console, then type `Person` you will get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

The variable user is scoped to onclick function and it does not exist outside. You can define user before as in the code below:

```
var Person = function (firstname, lastname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
};

var user;

document.getElementById('button').onclick = function () {

    var fn = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    var ln = document.getElementById('lname').value;

    function addPerson(person) {
        console.log(person);
    };

    user = new Person(fn, ln);

    addPerson(user);

};
```

Answer (score 0):

As is said in comments, typing "Person" into the console doesn't necessarily reflect the 'person' that was just created. Adding an array,

```
People = [];
var Person = function...
```

and then adding the new person to the array in your add person function,

```
People.push(person);
console.log(person);
```

allows you to now type in "People" in the console and see something you're looking for.